# How to build an intercalated ranking from two tables using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables in BigQuery with records ordered by a ranking. Given a ratio of integers, I want to be able to join both tables, keeping the order of the ranking and the proportions of the ratio of integers.
For example:

Table A

| Name | Ranking A |
| --- | --- |
| Kevin | 1 |
| Jack | 2 |
| Kate | 3 |
| Randall | 4 |
| Beck | 5 |

Table B:

| Name | Ranking B |
| --- | --- |
| William | 1 |
| Laurel | 2 |
| Sophie | 3 |
| Tess | 4 |
| Deja | 5 |
| Toby | 6 |
| Nick | 7 |

Given a ratio 2:3 where 2 corresponds with Table A, and 3 corresponds with Table B, the expected result would be:

| Name | Ranking A | Ranking B | Final Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kevin | 1 |  | 1 |
| Jack | 2 |  | 2 |
| William |  | 1 | 3 |
| Laurel |  | 2 | 4 |
| Sophie |  | 3 | 5 |
| Kate | 3 |  | 6 |
| Randall | 4 |  | 7 |
| Tess |  | 4 | 8 |
| Deja |  | 5 | 9 |
| Toby |  | 6 | 10 |
| Beck | 5 |  | 11 |
| Nick |  | 7 | 12 |

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with some math trick here. In both tables you have to compute a running sum and skip 2 (for second table) or 3 (for first table) values according to the ranking value you're currently placing. Basically you're making two gapped running sum, where the gaps will be filled by the other one's ranking values.

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MOD(RankingA,2) = 1 THEN 4 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY RankingA)-3 AS rn
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN MOD(RankingB,3) = 1 THEN 3 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY RankingB) AS rn
FROM tableB
ORDER BY rn
```

Then you just apply the `UNION ALL` operation and `ORDER BY` on the just generated ranking.

Comment: This is the perfect solution for me! As an additional consideration, if at some point you run out of observations in one of the tables, then the rn column will have some gaps. But you can fix this with an additional row_number() column. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Another approach would be:

```sql
SELECT name,
       IF(tbl = 1, rank, NULL) AS rankingA,
       IF(tbl = 2, rank, NULL) AS rankingB,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rank_grp, tbl, rank) final_rank 
  FROM (
    SELECT name, rankingA AS rank, DIV(rankingA - 1, 2) AS rank_grp, 1 AS tbl FROM tableA
     UNION ALL
    SELECT name, rankingB, DIV(rankingB - 1, 3), 2 FROM tableB
  );

+---------+----------+----------+------------+
|  name   | rankingA | rankingB | final_rank |
+---------+----------+----------+------------+
| Kevin   |        1 |          |          1 |
| Jack    |        2 |          |          2 |
| William |          |        1 |          3 |
| Laurel  |          |        2 |          4 |
| Sophie  |          |        3 |          5 |
| Kate    |        3 |          |          6 |
| Randall |        4 |          |          7 |
| Tess    |          |        4 |          8 |
| Deja    |          |        5 |          9 |
| Toby    |          |        6 |         10 |
| Beck    |        5 |          |         11 |
| Nick    |          |        7 |         12 |
+---------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try the following:

```
select Name, RankingA, RankingB,
       rank() over (order by NewRank) FinalRank
from
  (
   select Name, cast(RankingA as string) as RankingA , '' as RankingB,
       RankingA + floor((RankingA-1)/2)*3 as NewRank
   from TableA
   union all
   select Name, '', cast(RankingB as string), 
       RankingB + ceiling((RankingB)/3)*2
   from TableB
  ) T
```

`RankingA + floor((RankingA-1)/2)*3`: shifts each two consecutive RankingA values (1,2 and 3,4 and 5,6 ...) by n * 3 where n starts from 0.

`RankingB + ceiling((RankingB)/3)*2`: shifts each three consecutive RankingB values (1,2,3 and 4,5,6 ...) by n * 2 where n starts from 1.

Comment: See a [working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/K-1ri_J4) on MySQL.